# Updating all fields in an document using a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

I want to update all the fields in a MongoDB document and I have a Javascript object that contains all these fields. I could easily type out each field to update but this seems like a lot of manual work and not reusable.  I wanted to do something like below but this creates an object containing all the new field data within the document called newData.

I've tried JSON.stringify on the variable but the format isn't appropriate for update.

```
var newData = {
   _id:ObjectId("53245234..."),
   id: 88888,
   firstData: "someData",
   secondData: 787855,
   thirdData: [ 45,17,12,234]
};
var collection = db.get('CollectionToUpdate');

//strip out dB id so as not to overwrite it, possibly not needed
if ("_id" in newData) {
  delete newData["_id"];
}

//find the correct document based on program generated id and update
collection.update({id: newData.id}, {
   newData
})
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of req.query.newData ?

Comment: edited to simply show variable data instead of how the data is parsed from router.put function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust newData will not have any keys you don't intend (like update operators) this should work:

```
var collection = db.get('CollectionToUpdate');
collection.update({id: newData.id}, newData)
```

Note that this replaces the document. I assume that is what you meant by "update all the fields". `update` does not replace "_id".

[Documentation for `update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#field-value-expressions)

Comment: yikes, I didn't even think about the fact that I was putting the variable inside the {}, thanks!